# Famous/FamousEngine js using CDN

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn, famous-engine, famous-framework

I'm trying to use the current version of Famous in a browser, and can't find any way of doing it.  I can get version 0.3.0 working fine, but when I include:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.6.2/famous.min.js"></script>
```

and then use the code

```
var famous = require('famous')
```

it just fails badly - it seems it's using some completely different concept of "require" now.   Any idea of how to get this working?

Comment: I think you're meant to use the provided dev server.  If I were going to investigate, I would run the dev server and see what comes out in the page.  I think it transpiles your code, so I would take the output of the dev server (the Famous lib and your transpiled code) and use that as a starting point for running it outside of the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

hmm - I have a sort of answer - in that the above seems to define window.famous - so I just removed the require line.  It's somewhat unsatisfactory thought - as all the example code makes heavy use of the word "require" - so I'd still be interested in a requirejs friendly solution.